# Groups and Abelian

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these homework problems: 
Is this statement true or false:

The set $$\left \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x \ge 0 \right \}$$ is a group under the binary operation $\circ$ defined
by $$a \circ b = \sqrt{ab}.$$

2. Is the statement true or false:
   The set

$$S= 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\big|
ad-bc=0$$

is a group under matrix addition.
If it is false, explain.

For question 2, I thought that a proof by contradiction could be used.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. You should ask just one question per post (not two, as here) and use mathjax for mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: 1) Check each of the group axioms
2) What do you think? Is the sum of two matrices with determinant zero still a matrix of determinant zero? What about the other group axioms?

Comment: What have you already tried?  How have you tried to check the group axioms?

Answer (score 0):

The first is false because the binary is not associative. (a*b)*c = $\sqrt{\sqrt{abc^2}}$ $\neq$ $\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2bc}}$ = a*(b*c)

For the second question, yes, it is a group under addition. (1) associative (2) identity matrix exists (3) for each element in S, there is an inverse element in S.